# Using MMMarkdown, only system font will show bold or italicized text

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, markdown

I'm using MMMarkdown and when I apply no font to UILabel or UITextView (I have to keep UITextView so TTTAttributedLabel won't do), all of markdown works. When I give the label or textview a font, I only get markdown hyperlinks to work. I tried switching to the AttributedMarkdown library but hyperlinks don't work at all with that one.

In my Markdown Class:

```
class Markdown: NSObject {

func markdownString(stringForVideoDescription:NSString) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    var options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

    var error:NSError?

    var markdown:NSString = stringForVideoDescription
    var html:NSString = MMMarkdown.HTMLStringWithMarkdown(markdown, error: &error)

    var markdownAttributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32StringEncoding)!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil, error: &error)!

    if let font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Marion-Regular", size: 14) {
        markdownAttributedString.addAttributes([NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName], range: NSMakeRange(0, markdownAttributedString.length))
    }

    println(html) // used to see that markdown is in fact working

    return markdownAttributedString

}
```

In my view, I'm actually pulling from json api but I replace to test with:

```
let bodyText = "\*This* sample \[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)"

myTextView.attributedText = Markdown().markdownString(bodyText)
```

Do I need to set up css to specify font for each bold, italicized text? Any help is greatly appreciated as my designers don't want to use the default font of Times New Roman.